# How to take a screenshot in MacOS 9.2?

Tags: screen-capture, classic-mac-os

I am trying out an old install of MacOS 9.2, and can't remember how to take a screenshot. It is very hard to find any resources on MacOS 9.2 on the internet via search engines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google says:

- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>3</kbd>

  - takes a screen shot of the entire screen, and saves it to the root of your disk drive, as "Picture 1" (numbered sequentially).
- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>4</kbd>

  - turns the mouse pointer to a cross-hairs. Click and drag to get a screenshot of the selected area saved to the root of your disk drive, as "Picture 1" (numbered sequentially).

Files are PICT format, and open in SimpleText.  You can use [GraphicConverter](https://www.macintoshrepository.org/2434-graphicconverter-6-5-classic) to convert them to JPEG to bring them into the modern world.

Refs:
https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/cant-open-nor-convert-macos-9-screenshots.2253952/
https://www.kevinhooke.com/2020/07/18/converting-mac-os-9-pict-screenshot-files-to-jpegs/
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3899830?answerId=18214018022#18214018022

Comment: Also https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3899830?answerId=18214018022#18214018022

Comment: Thanks! Those links also answer my next question, which is how to convert to JPEG.

Comment: @PeterH.Boling you should edit much of the second paragraph of your answer into this one as it adds a lot to the answer, the current state is just links.

Comment: Updated the answer, thanks all!